# Почему github не запрашивает пароль и логин github при push(и т.п. команды)?

Tags: github, пароль, push, логин

Почему github не запрашивает пароль и логин github при push(и т.п. команды)? Может пароли где-то сохранились? (изменения на сайте гитхаб появляются)

Comment: Потому что ssh-ключ, может?

Comment: нет, ssh я предварительно убрал в другую папку(рабочий стол)